# Django/Visual Studio Tutorial - objects method error

Tags: django, python-3.x, visual-studio

I'm working through the Django Tutorial ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/)).  I'm using visual studio on a Mac and VS keeps showing an error on this code:

```
latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

The error reads `Class 'Question' has no 'objects' member`.

The example builds a `Questions Class` which in fact doesn't directly have an `objects` member, but the code runs fine and I think that there is a built in member within Django that has `objects`.

So that leads me to believe that the visual studio debugger is raising an error that doesn't actually exist.

Is there a way to fix this?

I've looked through `preferences/setting` and under `extensions` to see if there is a plugin or setting reference that could be made to Django to clear the error within Visual Studio - I didn't see anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is not error, just a warning from the Visual Studio Code. `objects` is a `Manager` instance which is added to our model classes dynamically by django. When VS Code checks the class declaration, it do not found objects declaration there, so warns us about a possible error.

In, Visual Studio code, python extension uses pylint as default linter.

To work it properly you can install pylint locally as:

```
pip install pylint
```

Or, you can also disable linting by configuring the following property in either one of (User or Workspace settings file) as follows:

```
"python.linting.enabled": false
```

**For django projects**, you can customize the pylint plugin by modifying the User or Workspace settings as follows:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"]
```

Comment: Thanks - I had the `pylint` enabled, but was missing the plugin for django.   Adding the plugin removed the warning. Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who gets "Expected comma" error in User Settings, put comma to previous argument and after this one `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"]`

Must be like this:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32\\python.exe",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "[python]": {

    },
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins", "pylint_django"
    ],
}
```