# Unable to import XXX module

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am just starting with Django, and I ran into some issues on my first project.

For some reason I am getting the following error: `Unable to import 'package name'`. Here is the picture :

[image]

As you can see, there were no issues identified when i try to run my Django Project. I've managed to create a simple `Http` call and everything still works perfectly fine.

But it bothers me that half of my project is red and it is showing error messages but no actual error when i run it.

When building my Django Projects I am using:

- Linux OS
- Python 3.65
- Django 2.02
- Visual Studio Code

If anyone has any idea whats going on I would really appreciate the help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: it's not error. It's due to the pylint in VS Code. Check answer here for pylint configuration with VS Code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951637/django-visual-studio-tutorial-objects-method-error/49952357#49952357

Comment: Did you ensure that the virtualenv is same for running the linter and code?