# Why can't I enable Pylint for this Django project using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am starting working with the Django Python framework (working on an [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) VM) following the famous Mozilla example project. This one: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Home_page

I am using the **Python 3.8.5** version.

I am finding the following problem (here on Stack Overflow I see that many persons had this problem and this should be related to Pylint).

Basically the problem is the same exposed here: *[Django/Visual Studio Tutorial - objects method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951637/django-visual-studio-tutorial-objects-method-error)*

I have this Django **views.py** file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from .models import Book, Author, BookInstance, Genre   

def index(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""

    # Generate counts of some of the main objects
    num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
    num_instances = BookInstance.objects.all().count()

    # Available books (status = 'a')
    num_instances_available = BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='a').count()

    # The 'all()' is implied by default.
    num_authors = Author.objects.count()

    context = {
        'num_books': num_books,
        'num_instances': num_instances,
        'num_instances_available': num_instances_available,
        'num_authors': num_authors,
    }

    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

The problem is that Visual Studio Code give me the following error on line like this:

```
num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
```

The error is:

> Class 'Book' has no 'objects' memberpylint(no-member)

And this is my **Book** class code:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    """Model representing a book (but not a specific copy of a book)."""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    # Foreign Key used because book can only have one author, but authors can have multiple books
    # Author as a string rather than object because it hasn't been declared yet in file.
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter a brief description of the book")
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN', max_length=13,
                            unique=True,
                            help_text='13 Character <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn'
                                      '">ISBN number</a>')
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text="Select a genre for this book")
    # ManyToManyField used because a genre can contain many books and a Book can cover many genres.
    # Genre class has already been defined so we can specify the object above.
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title', 'author']

    def display_genre(self):
        """Creates a string for the Genre. This is required to display genre in Admin."""
        return ', '.join([genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3]])

    display_genre.short_description = 'Genre'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular book instance."""
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.title
```

My code works fine so the error is not related to my code, but it is a lint error.

I tried to follow the steps indicated in this link: *[Django/Visual Studio Tutorial - objects method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951637/django-visual-studio-tutorial-objects-method-error)*

But it is not working. I still have this error in my IDE.

I have done it in this way:

1. I installed both these packages:

   ```
    pip3 install pylint
    pip3 install pylint-django
   ```

I installed these package both in the global environments and in the virtual environment used by my project.

2. Then I went into this folder: **~/Documenti/Python-WS/django_projects/locallibrary/.vscode$** (localibrary) is the folder related to my project and I edited the **settings.json** file, this one:

   ```
    (LOCAL-LIBRARY-TUTORIAL-ENV) andrea@ubuntu:~/Documenti/Python-WS/django_projects/locallibrary/.vscode$ ls -a
   ```

   .  ..  settings.json

I edited it in this way:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/andrea/Documenti/Python-WS/Environments/LOCAL-L>
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "[python]": {

    },
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins", "pylint_django"
    ],
}
```

Then I restarted Visual Studio Code, but it still have this error in the IDE:

[image]

What is wrong in my settings? How can I enable Python and Django lint on my project? What am I missing?

Moreover is there a way to globally enable this lint functionality for all my Python projects in order to avoid to set it for each projects?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself in the following way:

1. Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → here I search for "terminal" → in the search result I click on "edit in settings.json" (the procedure is shown in *[Visual Studio Code Tidbits: Visual Studio Code linting for Python (docstrings included)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMIxokGhFHM)*)
2. Differently from the previous link, I added some more Pylint settings related to Django, these into my **settings.json** file related to to my Visual Studio Code IDE:

   ```
    {
       "window.zoomLevel": 1,
       "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
       "terminal.integrated.automationShell.linux": "",
       "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
       "python.linting.pydocstyleEnabled": true,
       "python.linting.pydocstyleArgs": ["--ignore=D403, --ignore=E501"],
       "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"]
    }
   ```

Now it works fine.

Comment: I am pretty sure the name of the file is "settings.json" (though I couldn't find an authoritative source).